# Azure timer triggered function working locally but not triggering in portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm quite new to Azure and I'm developing a function that is triggered by a timer and then is supposed to send a string to an event hub. The function works properly when I run it locally - it connects to the event hub, which in turn connects to a data lake and deposits the event message data there - but when I deploy it and try to run it in the Azure portal it doesn't execute.

In my host.json file my connection is a string that is the name of one of the Function App Application Settings which in turn has the value of the connection string from the Event Hub namespace.

Any suggestions on why the function doesn't execute?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue: using a connection string from the Event Hub instance I wanted to use, rather than the namespace.